# How to achieve spring injection in oVal validation Framework?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, oval

This seems to be a big gap in it's spring integration. Has anybody done this or has successfully integrated Spring and Oval successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this myself. Read : http://sourceforge.net/projects/oval/forums/forum/488110/topic/3682975 for my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on what you mean by Spring integration.

Using the DbC feature in Spring: http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#d4e587

Check instances managed by Spring: http:// sourceforge.net/projects/oval/forums/forum/488110/topic/3682975

Comment: Hi that post was my solution. Thanks anyways.